# Dividir um array em novos arrays com limite de caracteres em cada um dos array

Tags: javascript, array

Meu problema é o seguinte:

Tenho a string de entrada: `"A|BB|CCC|DDDD|EEEEE|FFFFFF|GGGGGGG"`. Preciso dar um split nessa string no "|", para que no caso divida em 6.

Porém necessito que cada valor entre em um array de no máximo 10 caracteres e com os "|".

Por exemplo:

```
array(0) = "A|BB|CCC" //8 caracteres

array(1) = "DDDD|EEEEE" //10 caracteres

array(2) = "FFFFFF" //6 caracteres

array(3) = "GGGGGGG" //7 caracteres
```

Como eu fiz até agora:

- Utilizei o split para quebrar a string de entrada;
- Fiz um for no tamanho do array formado pela split;
- Percorro cada valor do array junto a um contador em um if que coloca os valores concatenados com "|" dentro do array.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui fazer com a função `dividePartes` abaixo. Clique no botão azul <kbd>Executar</kbd> para testar:

```js
function dividePartes(s) {
    var partes = s.split("|");
    var resultado = [];
    var pedaco = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < partes.length; i++) {
        var adicionando = pedaco;
        if (adicionando === "") {
            adicionando = partes[i];
        } else {
            adicionando += "|" + partes[i];
        }
        if (adicionando.length <= 10) {
            pedaco = adicionando;
        } else {
            resultado.push(pedaco);
            pedaco = partes[i];
        }
    }
    resultado.push(pedaco);
    return resultado;
}

var a = "A|BB|CCC|DDDD|EEEEE|FFFFFF|GGGGGGG";
document.write(JSON.stringify(dividePartes(a)));

var b = "A|BB|CCC|DDDD|EE|FFF|GG|HH|I|J|KKKKKKKKKKKK|LL|MM|NN";
document.write(JSON.stringify(dividePartes(b)));
```